# Application close notification in iphone when press home button twice

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

In iphone it when we press home button, application goes into the background. And then when we press home button twice we can see list of running applications. And then when we press that icon for long time one red round button comes, through which we can delete the app.

I wanted to know is there any notification comes for this particular situation in iphone.

Actually i wanted to handle this situation in my code, when we are closing our application by pressing home button twice.

Please tell me some solution and please let me know it there is any clarifications required regarding this question.

Thanks

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith, i didn't get your meaning. Actually i am not very much familiar with this forum. Can you please write your answer again, as i need it. Thanks.

Comment: oh, i am so so sorry, i wasn't know this. From the next time i will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343404/how-to-know-whether-app-is-terminated-by-user-or-ios-after-10min-background), when a user kills an app, it's a SIGKILL (as opposed to when iOS kills the app, which calls applicationWillTerminate).

You cannot execute code for when a user kills the app, only for some general application states, such as active, background, suspended, and inactive. Check out [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) on app states.

Answer (score 4):

You should not (and can not) handle this specifically, because when the user double presses the home key and kills your app, that is what the user intends to do - he wants to kill your app.

The most common reasons for doing this is because there is a problem with your app. Another reason could be that the user tries to cheat your app somehow (for example in a game), so the strategy I would recommend for you is:

1. Build your app well, so the user will not terminate it because of
   problems =)
2. Save your application data and application state in
   the "applicationWillEnterBackground" event. This way you are
   guaranteed that the user will not loose any data if he/she closes
   the    app (in a normal manner)
3. If you think the user will try to
   "cheat"    your app, save your application data in critical moments
   while the    app is running. For example if you are making a game
   and the player    fails a mission, save the app state immediately so
   that the player    cannot cheat by killing the app.

Comment: If another answer helped you more than the accepted answer, you can actually change which answer is the accepted one. (just for your information, not saying this one is better ;)) So it is OK to wait for a while before accepting.
Always select the answer that was the most helpful to answer the question as the accepted one. Good luck.

Comment: i would give the same answer as jake_hetfield.

Answer (score 2):

When you double tap on the home button the list of apps shown is not al list of apps running. But a list of apps started. Sorted by the app that was start last. That the app is in this list does not mean that it is running.

When you kill an app here your app does not receive any notification that it is about to be killed. Your apps is thus not closed but killed.

iOS might kill your app when it background if the system needs to free memory. Again your app will not be notified in any way. (*but this time it will stay in de list that popsup when you double tap the home button*)

Comment: Also, when you have "Application does not run in background" set to "YES" in info.plist your app will still show on the double-press-home-button list but it will not be running. (At least in iOS 5).