# Close MobilePhone, MobileSMS app not success

Tags: iphone, sqlite, jailbreak

How can I close an app with system("/usr/bin/killall [appname]");
i used it but when I double tap on Home button to show background app. it still appear.
May help?
I deverlop on Jailbroken phone, I want to clear call_history.db, I guess I want to close MobilePhone app perfectly, after that I can delete on call_history.

Comment: I really want to know this answer. +1 for asking such question

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure for this answer. However, I believe if you double tap Home button it doesn't show you a list of *background* apps. It shows you a list of *recently used* apps.

As example, system may stop some of this apps due to low memory, but they are still on this list. If you click on any of stopped apps, they will be started by system again.

Based on this understanding. Most likely Killall actually worked fine (killed an app), but the app stayed in recent apps list. You don't need to worry about this list for your task.

Comment: I try to delete from call_history.db with MobilePhone is openning and it still appear on Recent Call, but when I close MobilePhone by double tap Home button and open it again, it not appear.

Comment: That's odd. I am not sure. May be there is additional some daemon running which is stopped, when you stop MobilePhone through UI and which keeps call history. Try to get a list of processes, stop MobilePhone through UI and get list of processes again and compare it.

Comment: +1.  This is correct.  If you `killall` the app, the process is gone, but it will still show in the recently used app list (Double-Press Home Button).  [See Apple doc here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4211), or [other answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11117564/119114).

Comment: system("/usr/bin/killall MobilePhone");
I don't know how it returns?

Comment: @user1561904: What do you mean by "I don't know how it returns"?

Comment: Sorry for my English :D
It means: "The return value of "system("/usr/bin/killall MobilePhone")" "

Comment: @user1561904: Not a problem. I am not a native speaker either :) Take a look at this (for a return value) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/